# Highcharts - change seconds to time (H:M:S) in data labels

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How to change the value on the chart to present it as HH:MI:SS and not as a seconds?

[image]

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                }
            },{ // Secondary yAxis
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall'
                },
                 gridLineWidth: 0,
                    type: 'datetime', //y-axis will be in milliseconds
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: { //force all formats to be hour:minute:second
                        second: '%H:%M:%S',
                        minute: '%H:%M:%S',
                        hour: '%H:%M:%S',
                        day: '%H:%M:%S',
                        week: '%H:%M:%S',
                        month: '%H:%M:%S',
                        year: '%H:%M:%S'
                    },
                opposite: true
            }],
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [17.0*1000, 16.9*1000, 19.5*1000, 114.5*1000, 118.4*1000, 121.5*1000, 125.2*1000, 126.5*1000, 123.3*1000, 118.3*1000, 113.9*1000, 19.6*1000]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9UGJc/

**Working example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/9UGJc/3/

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                }
            },{ // Secondary yAxis
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall'
                },
                 gridLineWidth: 0,
                    type: 'datetime', //y-axis will be in milliseconds
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: { //force all formats to be hour:minute:second
                        second: '%H:%M:%S',
                        minute: '%H:%M:%S',
                        hour: '%H:%M:%S',
                        day: '%H:%M:%S',
                        week: '%H:%M:%S',
                        month: '%H:%M:%S',
                        year: '%H:%M:%S'
                    },
                opposite: true
            }],
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function(){
                            if( this.series.index == 0 ) {
                                return secondsTimeSpanToHMS(this.y/1000) ;
                            } else {
                                return this.y;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [17*1000, 16*1000, 19*1000, 114*1000, 118*1000, 121*1000, 125*1000, 126*1000, 123*1000, 118*1000, 113*1000, 19*1000]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });
    });

function secondsTimeSpanToHMS(s) {
    var h = Math.floor(s / 3600); //Get whole hours
    s -= h * 3600;
    var m = Math.floor(s / 60); //Get remaining minutes
    s -= m * 60;
    return h + ":" + (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + ":" + (s < 10 ? '0' + s : s); //zero padding on minutes and seconds
}
```

Comment: brief what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Hamza, I've just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [datalabels formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter) and use [Highcharts.dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat)

Comment: OK< but formatter is only for `plotOptions` and it changes all series.  But I want to modify only one.

Comment: In the formatter you can recognise which series you have, by index

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create that function:

```
function secondsTimeSpanToHMS(s) { 
    var h = Math.floor(s / 3600); //Get whole hours
    s -= h * 3600;
    var m = Math.floor(s / 60); //Get remaining minutes
    s -= m * 60;
    return h + ":" + (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + ":" + (s < 10 ? '0' + s : s); zero padding on minutes and seconds
}
```

in your code (http://jsfiddle.net/9UGJc/3/) at 39 line alter the code to:

```
return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update this value

```
data: [17.0*1000, 16.9*1000, 19.5*1000, 114.5*1000, 118.4*1000, 121.5*1000, 125.2*1000, 126.5*1000, 123.3*1000, 118.3*1000, 113.9*1000, 19.6*1000]
        }
```

use this script to convert integer to time format

```
    var seconds = 9999;// multiply by 1000 because Date() requires milliseconds
    var date = new Date(seconds * 1000);
    var hh = date.getUTCHours();
    var mm = date.getUTCMinutes();
    var ss = date.getSeconds();
    // This line gives you 12-hour (not 24) time
    if (hh > 12) {hh = hh - 12;}
    // These lines ensure you have two-digits
    if (hh < 10) {hh = "0"+hh;}
    if (mm < 10) {mm = "0"+mm;}
    if (ss < 10) {ss = "0"+ss;}
    // This formats your string to HH:MM:SS
    var t = hh+":"+mm+":"+ss;
    document.write(t);
```

or Use this,

```
    var t = 34236; // your seconds
    var time = ('0'+Math.floor(t/3600) % 24).slice(-2)+':'+('0'+Math.floor(t/60)%60).slice(-2)+':'+('0' + t % 60).slice(-2)
    //would output: 09:30:36
```

Comment: so why it won't work like this? http://jsfiddle.net/9UGJc/2/
I can also get value in H:M:S from db..

Comment: It must be an number.